# Rails Devise custom mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer

I want to add new mailer methods to Devise that mostly copy the workflow of the built-in ones but with some added parameters and different views.

For example reset_password_instructions is used in two cases:

1. When an existing user simply wants to reset his password.
2. When a user invites another user, that user is saved in the database with a randomized password. He is sent an email with a reset_password_token that should redirect him to the edit password page so he could later sign in.

Same functionality, but I want the second email to have a different view, and also I need to be able to pass in the name of the person who sent the invitation.

It is very confusing because Devise mailers call a bunch of other methods and helpers so I don't know what methods to rewrite in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use a custom mailer, create a class that extends `Devise::Mailer`, like this:

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
end
```

Then, in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, set `config.mailer` to `"MyMailer"`.

You may now use your `MyMailer` in the same way as any other mailer. In case you want to override specific mails to add extra headers, you can do so by simply overriding the method and calling `super` at the end of your custom method, to trigger Devise's default behavior.

For instance, we can add a new header for the `confirmation_instructions` e-mail as follows:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
  super
end
```

You can also override any of the basic headers (from, reply_to, etc) by manually setting the options hash:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
  opts[:from] = 'my_custom_from@domain.com'
  opts[:reply_to] = 'my_custom_from@domain.com'
  super
end
```

In order to get preview (if `User` is your devise model name):

```
# test/mailers/previews/my_mailer_preview.rb
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/my_mailer

class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def confirmation_instructions
    MyMailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    MyMailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end

  def unlock_instructions
    MyMailer.unlock_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end
end
```

In order to control which queue name the mailer queues up new email, add the following method to your class (`MyMailer`, above):

```
def deliver_later
   Devise::Mailer.delay(queue: 'my_queue').send(...)
end
```